# meaning of 'glib' in 'glib uniformity'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The phrase 'glib uniformity' has been used in at least [a few books](https://www.google.com/search?q=glib%20uniformity&client=firefox-b-ab&tbm=bks&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN2KHiqt7fAhUP2qQKHYBNCxgQ_AUIDigA&biw=1525&bih=730&dpr=0.9). For example, in *Political Ideals* (1917), Bertrand Russell wrote

> The state is justified in insisting that children shall be educated, but it is not justified in forcing their education to proceed on a uniform plan and to be directed to the production of a dead level of **glib uniformity**.

I'm not sure which [dictionary definition of 'glib'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glib) is nearest to what was meant by Russell. Did he mean *superficial uniformity*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I'm not sure which dictionary definition of 'glib' is nearest to what
  was meant by Russell. Did he mean superficial uniformity?

My sense would be yes, superficial but leaning heavily to the *deceitful*. The latter implies the potential for harm. Even his use of a *dead level* invokes a level that causes harm.  The need for education is a given.  For the state to attempt to forcefully implement it can be harmful.

**glib**  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glib)

> 1. showing little forethought or preparation : offhand glib answers
> 2. lacking depth and substance : superficial glib solutions to knotty
>      problems
> 3. to the point of being insincere or deceitful

Answer (score 5):

Yes, superficial is the meaning intended.

According to Collins Dictionary:

> If you describe what someone says as glib, you disapprove of it because it implies that something is simple or easy, or that there are no problems involved, when this is not the case. [disapproval]
>
> - *Mr. Lewis takes an insufferably glib attitude toward it all.*